# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^+}(\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x)\right)$$

Now, when I plot the function; $$\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x)$$ it seems that the limit would be $$\infty$$

However, $$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1}{x} =\infty = \lim_{x\to0^+} (-\ln(x) )$$

So wouldn't that mean that $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x)\right) = 0 ?$$

I haven't been over limits for a while and feel like I'm forgetting something or making a silly mistake. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: $\infty+\infty=\infty$.

Comment: Even if you "had" $\infty-\infty$, you could not conclude this is zero. You'd need to be more cautious

Comment: Hint: $$
\lim _{x \to 0^ +  } \left( {\frac{1}{x} - \ln (x)} \right) = \lim _{x \to 0^ +  } \left( {\frac{1}{x} + \ln \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right) = \lim _{y \to  + \infty } (y + \ln (y)).
$$ Can you conclude?

Comment: You can separate the limit of differences as the difference of limits if those limits exist. If they are infinity, you should treat the difference as a whole. A simple example: consider the function $2x - x$. As $x$ approaches infinity, $2x-x$ approaches also infinity, since $2x - x = x$. But if you separate, you will get $\infty - \infty$, which would make no sense. You cannot treat them as you do with finite numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies, I get it now!